# EF Core 7 Converting Table UTC to Local Timezone

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, timezone

Using SQL I can do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM [T1].[dbo].[Orders]
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time') 
BETWEEN '2023-12-06' AND '2023-12-07'
ORDER BY OrderId DESC;
```

This shows the records as expected,
however I'm wanting to achieve the same using EF Core without having to use Enumerable or ToList.

```
query = query.Where(order =>
     EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(
         TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(order.OrderDate, TimeZoneInfo.Utc),
         TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(startDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local)
     ) >= 0 &&
     EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(
         TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(endDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local),
         TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(order.OrderDate, TimeZoneInfo.Utc)
     ) >= 0);
```

It appears I have misunderstood how to correctly convert the timezone judging by the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'. ---> System.ArgumentException: The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind property set correctly.  For example, when the Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be TimeZoneInfo.Local. (Parameter 'sourceTimeZone')

**Update**
I have attempted the solutions from both answers, however the results are not the same as in SQL.
Something I noticed with the above SQL query, all the results are correct, however after this one, they are missing.
[image]

as you can see, the results crossover 3 days.

Comment: Cop-Out: Have the FrontEnd / Api Client provide you UTC dates, only. (General advice, but probably not helpful for you ...) Alternatively: Can you draw the conversion out of the EF-Statement?

Comment: Could always convert the local date time provider to UTC and then leave it for the front end to convert it back, was hoping to avoid something like given how nice the SQL statement works.

Comment: What's the column type ? If it's DateTimeOffset, no conversion is needed. The UI can convert it to the end user's timezone without trouble. Next best is if you're ABSOLUTELY certain that the database time is UTC, to force EF to set the DateTimeKind to UTC, eg through a converter.

Comment: I wish it was an offset, unfortunately the column type is datetime

Comment: @traveler3468 MJP mentioned in comments that the correct conversion is `startDate.Date.ToUniversalTime()`, not `startDate.ToUniversalTime().Date`. He's right. For a short period every day, a local date will translate to a different date part in UTC, eg `2023-12-02 01:00 +02:00` is `2023-12-01 23:00` as UTC. Truncating after the conversion results in the wrong date

Answer (score 2):

In the question's case it's infinitely easier to convert the filter parameters to UTC than try to convert the stored dates.

Instead of casting to date, it's better to use an open end date. Indexes can't accelerate filtering function results. `CAST( ... AS DATE)` is almost an exception: the database can convert it to a range query but can't use the column's statistics to determine whether it makes sense to use an index or not.

This snippet solves both problems. The dates are converted to UTC and truncated. The End date is the day *after* the original end date:

```
var startDateUtc= startDate.Date.ToUniversalTime();
var endDateUtc  = endDate.Date.ToUniversalTime()
                      .AddDays(1);

query=query.Where(order=>order.OrderDate >= startDateUtc && 
                         order.OrderDate <  endDateUtc);
```

In other scenarios, `AT TIME ZONE` is available through [EF.Functions.AtTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.attimezone?view=efcore-7.0). That method returns the value as a DateTimeOffset, so there's no need for a double conversion.

For example, you can convert the UTC OrderDate to a DateTimeOffset value with :

```
query = query.Select(order =>new ReportOrder {
            ...
            OrderDate= EF.Functions.AtTimeZone(order.OrderDate,"UTC"),
            ...
        });
```

---

In a **desktop** application, where you know that the "Local" time is also the user's local time, you can convert to local time with `DateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime()`. I'm not sure if you can use `ToLocalTime()` in the `Select`, but you can add a calculated property to `ReportOrder` that would return the local time :

```
public class ReportOrder
{
    public required DateTimeOffset OrderDate {get;set;}

    [NotMapped]    
    public DateTimeOffset OrderDateLocal =>OrderDate.ToLocalTime();

}
```

Comment: The approach is correct, but there are two issues here.  1) You shouldn't call `.Date` after converting to UTC.  The column is a `datetime` type with the data in terms of UTC, so the point's you're querying should include the UTC date and time, not the UTC time at midnight.

Comment: 2) `ToLocalTime` and `ToUniversalTime` use the computer's own time zone setting.  If this code is running server-side, such as with an ASP.NET application, chances are that time zone is not the end-user's time zone.  It's probably UTC already.  So, the conversions should be done with `TimeZoneInfo` methods, using a time zone ID appropriate for the user.

Comment: But great point about indexes.  Any SQL statement having a filtering function on the left side of the comparison is going to be [non-sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/634824).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint it's the Toy Maker's fault (couldn't resist). You're right. It's not like I haven't run into this exact problem multiple times in the past .... Some of Sabre's web services (one of the big air tickets GDSs) have a hard-coded conversion to Texas time. Want all tickets for a date? Use a date+time that gets converted to 12 AM in Texas. And *one* service has different conversions from mainframe to web server, and web server to client.

Answer (score 0):

Convert local variables to UTC and convert `OrderDate` to UTC also, via `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc`.
Then write LINQ query similar to your SQL:

```cs
startDateTime = startDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
endDateTime = endDateTime.ToUniversalTime();

query = query.Where(order =>
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(order.OrderDate) >= startDateTime && 
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(order.OrderDate) <= endDateTime
        )
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderId);
```

Comment: There's no need for `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` if the filter dates are UTC.  `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AUS ...'` is used to tell the server that a `datetime` is `UTC` and *then* convert it to `AUS ..`. That means the `datetime` values are already UTC.